# limited resources assignment problem in CP-SAT solver with or-tools

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

the problem consists of the following data table:

**update:** I correct channel for user. each user comes from only ONE channel and may collect different number of items (count_item as showed in the following table). and changed *task* to *task_type* for clarification, previously *task* was misleading to the number of task but it is categorical variable.

| user | channel | task_type | value | count_item | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | A1 | T1 | 100 | 12 | 20 |
| U1 | A1 | T2 | 120 | 22 | 33 |
| U1 | A1 | T3 | 100 | 12 | 20 |
| U1 | A1 | T4 | 100 | 12 | 20 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| Un | A6 | T1 | 200 | 30 | 90 |
| Un | A6 | T2 | 150 | 22 | 103 |
| Un | A6 | T3 | 80 | 15 | 120 |
| Un | A6 | T4 | 40 | 40 | 60 |

##### Explanation:

The total budget is limited, for example 1M, and total channels is 6, and total tasks is 4, and total users can be tens of thousands.

##### Conditions:

each user can **ONLY** be assigned to **ONE** task_type, but can be assigned zero times or at most k times for example **0<=k<=12**.
total assigned tasks have limited budget, say $ \sum_i^M {Cost_i * Cnt_i} <= Budget $ where i loops for assigned users (M<=N, probably M<N) and occurrences of this user. Correct my if I states a wrong formula for calculating the total costs.
**update:** all calculations of costs and values are subject to for example:
a. the count_item > 12
OR
b. its value > 105

##### Targets:

to achieve MOST values of all assigned users , say $ maximize( \sum_i^M {Value_i * Cnt_i} )$, please correct me if my formulation is incorrect.

##### Idea:

I am planning to use cp-sat solver with or-tools to solve this, however, I am entirely newbie to the field of OR. I don't know whether cp-sat with or-tools is suitable for this problem, for example cpu efficiency and memory efficiency.

Comment: “$ maximize( \sum_i^M {Value_i * Cnt_i} )$”.   Just curious what language this is?